# Ajax notification to user, when he/she gets answers to his/her question or comments points to him/her?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, global-inbox, ajax

I realize that the notification is there on a hard page refresh, but I would like to avoid refreshing the page to see that I got an answer or comment.

Comment: @Gaurav - some more information needed. What do you mean by Ajax notification?

Comment: @Sachin : I need not to refresh the page to see I got any answer or comment or not.

Comment: @Gaurav - That feature is already available since it notifies you on top left corner of screen when you get any new answers or comments. ;)

Comment: @Sachin : But It notifies me when I refresh the page.

Comment: @Gaurav - Oh.. ok, got your point :)

Comment: Sounds like comet/long-polling, which could potentially be very many persistent connections to the server.

Comment: @hyperslug - there is already such polling (every 45 seconds I think) in every question page that alert the user when new answer is posted to the question, or when the question is closed or deleted. So having the polling do some extra work shouldn't really be big burden. :)

Comment: @Gaurav - do you mean "Ajaxify" the global inbox so it will suddenly come to life showing a number all by itself? This *can* be cool indeed.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard : yes.

Answer (score 5):

The cost/benefit ratio on this is kind of out of whack.

While we could reduce it on *question* pages, those are the only ones with a regular poll going on; every other page would gain a new background poller (or long polling, or whatever*).

That's a lot of potential load for marginal gain.

We may revisit this if we find more compelling "polling everywhere" features, since we could piggy-back on those requests.  But for now, this is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

<sub>*Fetching the number is cheap, the # of connections is the nasty bit w.r.t. scaling.</sub>