# Display global inbox count on tab title

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox, browsers

Just like in Gmail, Yahoo!Mail and many other web apps. Just a number in brackets. So I can keep strolling the web while waiting for responses.

**Firefox 4 mockup:**

[image]

Comment: On all pages?  Or just the main page?  It doesn't seem to make much sense on pages with questions in the title and such

Comment: A [related request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85414/ajax-notification-to-user-when-he-she-gets-answers-to-his-her-question-or-commen), though I believe that one merely wants updates to the red marker itself rather than the tab. Nevertheless, I imagine the judgment on this will be much the same.

Comment: Hmm.. I forgot there was no automatic refresh. So until we have that one, we can't have this. Good point @Grace.

Comment: @Daniel, only in the main pages. It will do.

Comment: Nice suggestion, once the inbox will be ajaxified.. :)