# Getting Notifications without a Refresh?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ajax notification to user, when he/she gets answers to his/her question or comments points to him/her?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85414/ajax-notification-to-user-when-he-she-gets-answers-to-his-her-question-or-comme)

I noticed something when it came to the notifications bar at the top of the Stackoverflow header: I have to refresh the page in order to get notification.

I know that Facebook uses some sort of post/get script (sorry if that is not what is used, just a guess) so that the user does not have to refresh the page to get new content. I believe I have seen this on the Stackoverflow site already in a few places, but I was wondering if the notifications bar could be changed in order to get new notifications from the server.

Bottom line: Would it be possible to get the notifications portal link to give notifications without a page refresh, or is this built into the StackExchange?

Comment: Already declined: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85414/ajax-notification-to-user-when-he-she-gets-answers-to-his-her-question-or-comme