# Popup on answer/comment on my question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'd like to know if there is a way to get some popups when someone answer or comment on a question. I'm thinking about something like the badge gained or reputation cap reached warning on the top of the screen (sort of orange line if I remember right).

Notifications via emails are kinda floody and no notification = spam F5, which is boring.

Comment: This has already [been suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85414/ajax-notification-to-user-when-he-she-gets-answers-to-his-her-question-or-comme) and declined before..

Comment: @ShadowWizard The question you linked is actually about having new notifications without to refresh the page, while this question is talking of getting a notification similar to the one you get for a new gained badge.

Answer (score 5):

There are already notifications that you get on the "StackExchange" popup. When there is a new comment, or a new answer for your question, a number appears to the right side of that popup.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

To notice that those notifications are passed along the network of sites; for example, if I have a comment on an answer I gave on Meta Stack Overflow, and I am reading a question on Stack Overflow, or Drupal Answers, I would get notified the same; I would not need to be on Meta Stack Overflow to get my notifications.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

If you are getting those notifications via email is probably because you set them to be received via email.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Normally, those notifications are not given through via email, and new comments/answers directed to you are reported in the Super Drop-down Menu®.

If you are suggesting a notification on the top bar saying that you have X new comments (or X new answers), that is already done with the number that appears close to the Super Drop-down Menu®. If you are suggesting a notification on the top bar for each new comment (or answer), that would be not practice, as you could get many notifications (even higher than 10, depending on how much frequently you visit the SE sites where you have an account). Supposing that the notifications would appear all in the same instant, they could become a wall; if they appear one after the other, they would be less practical than the actual notifications.

If I have to choose between the actual notification system, and the one you propose, I prefer the actual system. Clearly, both the notifications could not co-exist, and having both of them would be a not necessary duplication of code.

Comment: **ARRRG!** THE BLUE kills my eyes! not enough red lines!

Comment: I didnt active the email notification, I was mentionning it as a (sucky) alternative !
I know about what u said but if u don't click on the "stackexchange" symbol, you are not noticed... :(
I was talking about popups so that u can notice it instantly but I admit that its not time consuming to click on the symbol uh :)
There ain't any alternative ?

Comment: I am sorry; I am used to using the red for highlighting grammar errors. `:-)` Thank you for the comment, though; it allowed me to take a screenshot of a real notification. `:-)`

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne Well, that number tells you that you have X notifications, so it is notifying you about the notifications. `:-)`

Comment: You and your heretic non-freehand arrows! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You mean a "popup" that will notify you while you're sitting idle on the page?  Your reasoning is that re-loading all the time is resource-consuming (or that spam F5 is boring, I'm not sure if there's a difference).  However, this "popup" would have to be polling all the time.  Always.  Even if you're not expecting it to find something, it's still going to poll.  Sure, it would be optimized very well, but it's going to add up to a *lot* of resource usage across the entire Stack Exchange community.

Just re-visit the page from time to time.  The Stack Exchange inbox in the top left will tell you when there's something new.